# if loop not working properly

Tags: apex

I have the below code which is giving incorrect if loop condition. 
If i dont upload a file it gives me correct error message file not found.

If i upload a file more than 25 mb . it is again going to the line which is telling file not found and another error "This file exceeds the maximum size limit of 25MB.
"

```
   public with sharing class RFPControllerExtension {
    private RFP__c currentRFP;

    public RFPControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {


        this.currentRFP = (RFP__c) controller.getRecord();

        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('DealId') != null) {
            currentRFP.Deal__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('DealId');
        }

        currentRFP.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserID();  


    }

    public string fileName { get; set; }   
    public Transient Blob fileBody { get; set; }
    public PageReference editAll()
    {
        id rfprecord = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');  
        RFP__c  currentRFP1= [select id from RFP__c where id=: rfprecord];
        PageReference rfpPage = (new ApexPages.StandardController(currentRFP1)).edit();  
        rfpPage.setRedirect(true);
        return rfpPage;
    }

    public PageReference saveAll() {
        Attachment rfpAttachment  = new Attachment();

        try {

            list< attachment> att= new list<attachment>();

            if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null)
            {

                id rpid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
                att= [select id from attachment where parentid=: rpid] ; 

            }


            if(fileBody == null && currentRFP.Pitch_Deck__c == null && currentRFP.type__c != '' && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') == null) {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,System.Label.RFP_File_Load)); 
            }
            else if(att.size()==0 && currentRFP.Pitch_Deck__c == null && currentRFP.type__c != '' && ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id') != null)
            {
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,System.Label.RFP_File_Load));
            }


            else {

                if(fileBody != null && fileName != null ) {
                    system.debug('*******');
                    rfpAttachment.Body = fileBody;
                    rfpAttachment.Name = fileName;
                    //rfpAttachment.ParentId = currentRFP.Id;
                    if(fileBody.size() <=25000000) { 

                        upsert currentRFP; 
                    }else{
                    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'File Too Large'));
                   return null;

                   } 

                }

                if(currentRFP.Id != null ){
                    rfpAttachment.ParentId = currentRFP.Id;
                    insert rfpAttachment;

                }else{

                   ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.WARNING,'File Not Found'));
                   return null;

                } 
                string url;

                url = '/apex/RFPDetail?id=' + currentRFP.id + '&Dealid=' +currentRFP.Deal__c;
                PageReference pRef =  new PageReference(url);  
                pRef.setRedirect(true);
                return pRef;
            }

            return null;
        } catch (System.Exception e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'Error uploading file' + e)); 
            return null;
        }        
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell what is going wrong?

Comment: What is the required behaviour? The if-statement on line 6 looks strange as it is doing 2 check of which the first is not relevant as it will always be smaller than 5242880 if it is smaller than 25000000..

Comment: May i know where you are using this if condition?
While saving the record means, you might have given the return type on that method...But if you are using this if condition directly in any of the return type methods like "save", The Messages won't work because of that return type....

Comment: Agreed with @Guy. The "if" in line 6 needs to be revised, because it doesn't make much sense. We're missing more context (ie: more code) to understand what `rfpAttachment` and `currentRFP` are.

Comment: i ahve updated my code. Saveall() method is called after which this error occurs

Comment: does it work correct for files under 25mb?

Comment: Yes it's working fine

Comment: How do you get two errors messages with that code? The 'file not found` is followed by a `return null;` which means nothing is executed after it.  Can you clarify the exact messages and when they occur?